# How to build connection string from existing connection for new database created dynamically?

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, connection-string

I have query to dynamically create database.

```
    private void ExecuteNonQuery(string sql)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = sql;
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    private void CreateDatabase(string databaseName)
    {
        try
        {
            ExecuteNonQuery($"CREATE DATABASE {databaseName}");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Can't create database '{databaseName}'");
        }
    }
```

Database will be created using my existing connection , But I need to create connection string for this new database to run migration and for various other purposes.

How is it possible ?

#### Update

**Its actually for purpose where users can fill a form to create a new database where they can give their existing connection string or if they don't have one in hand we build it for them**

Answer (score 0):

use this function to get a connection to the new database:

```
private SqlConnection NewDatebaseConnection(string databaseName)
    {
        SqlConnection  connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        connection.ChangeDatabase(databaseName);
        return SqlConnection;  
    }
```

Comment: This will not resole my question.  As Iam stated in the question I need the connection string so that I can save it in a separate file and reuse .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EF, you should have a context to work with, something like the following:

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public MyContext():base("myConnectionStringName")
    {
    }
}
```

The [constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext.dbcontext(v=vs.113).aspx) has a parameter that specifies connection name or a connection string. So, you can obtain a context for any connections string you want:

```
using (var db = new MyContext("connection_string_containing_new_db") 
{
    // do stuff with the context
}
```

You should consider using a factory that builds such contexts:

```
class MyContextFactory
{
    MyContext CreateContextForDatabase(string dbName) 
    {
         var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
         builder["Data Source"] = "server\\instance";
         builder["integrated Security"] = true;
         builder["Initial Catalog"] = dbName;

         return new new MyContext(builder.ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

The code uses [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) to construct (from scratch) the connection string. An alternative is to parse a static connection string using `var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(staticConnectionString)` and only change the `Initial Catalog`.

Comment: :) you said everything except the answer for building a connection string . How to identify the existing connection and build a connection string accordingly using SqlConnectionStringBuilder?

Comment: @Sachin - that's true :). I have edited my answer to show how connection string can be built.

Comment: Iam actually addressing an issue where the format of connection strings can change according to the provider right , so how can we just blindly go for one particular format?

Comment: I done these already and working fine , but my I need a solution for a general case  ?

Comment: @Sachin - how general? This should allow connecting to any database using EF.

Comment: connection string format varies according to providers right? So I need to build a new one only after analysing the existing one. Is that possible.

Comment: @Sachin - Yes, the factory class should take care of this of that based on a configuration stored somewhere: host, instance, provider type (e.g. ADO.NET, Oracle, Teradata.Net).

Answer (score 0):

To save new connection, you can use `ConnectionStringBuilder` with existing connection, change the name of database and save it to `app.config`.

1.Helper method to get connection string:

```
string GetConnectionString(string name) =>
          ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[name].ConnectionString;
```

2.Helper method which saves new connection string to app.config:

```
void CreateNewConnectionString(string baseName, string newName, string newDatabaseName)
{
    // Get the connection string a new connection will be based on
    string baseConnString =
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[baseName].ConnectionString;
    // For simplicity of manipulations with connection strings,
    // we use SqlConnectionStringBuilder, passing it an existing connection string
    var connBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(baseConnString);
    // Change existing database name to the new database name
    connBuilder.InitialCatalog = newDatabaseName;
    // Create new settings, holding our new connection string
    var newConnection = new ConnectionStringSettings(newName, connBuilder.ToString());
    // Save new connection string
    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Add(newConnection);
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
}
```

3.Usage

```
private void CreateDatabase(string databaseName)
{
    try
    {
        // Create database using "main" connection string
        ExecuteNonQuery($"CREATE DATABASE {databaseName}", "main");
        // Create new connection string "my_db" based on "main"
        CreateNewConnectionString("main", "my_db", databaseName);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Can't create database '{databaseName}'");
    }
}
```

Comment: One doubt is , what if the existing connection is a LocalDB with an attacheFile mdf with it ? what will be the attachedFile path for the new database?

Comment: @Sachin You can set and change everything you need in [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder). Rather basing builder on existing connection, you can create your own brand-new connection from scratch. So, this is not a problem: builder.[AttachDBFilename](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.attachdbfilename).

Comment: Iam actually addressing an issue where the format of connection strings can change according to the provider right , so how can we just blindly go for one particular format?

Comment: I done these already and working fine , but my I need a solution for a general case  ?

Comment: @Sachin So, SqlConnectionStringBuilder doesn't fit you?